# How do I always maximize the window without having to call it in each function?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, behat, mink

In `JUnit`, I would have done this in an `@Before` method but I don't see that in Mink. Does anyone know how to do this for all the tests instead of having to do `$this->getSession()->maximize()` in every function? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backgrounds or feature hooks. Both work similarly to the setUp method used in xUnit frameworks.

Backgrounds are more explicit:

```
Feature: your feature

Background:
    Given the window is maximized

Scenario: Log in
    Given I press the login button
    Then I should see "logged in"
```

And with hooks, you can have a FeatureContext method executed. Maybe this is more appropiate:

```
/** @BeforeFeature */
public static function setupFeature(FeatureEvent $event)
{
}
```

Read more at the docs:

- [backgrounds](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#backgrounds)
- [feature hooks](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/3.hooks.html#feature-hooks)

Comment: Thanks friend, much appreciated. Thanks for the referral to the docs as well.